# Simple Math Equation find sum of 4 numbers and if greater then number X reduce all 4 numbers respectively

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Im not the greatest at Math but i have the following problem:

impressions = 791.

watched 100 = 500

watched 75 = 383

watched 50 = 600

watched 25 = 700

The sum of all watched fields is **2183**.

Since the sum of all watched fields is greater then impressions i want to reduce the numbers in each of the 4 fields until the sum of all 4 fields equal impressions.

I have tried many methods such as finding the percentage of 791 in 2183. Then using that percentage reduce each 4 fields respectively, but i never get a flush number.

Any ideas?

Edit: Example of 1 of my many failed attemps :p

```
    2183 - 791 / 2183 = 0.63
    0.63

    500 X 0.63 = 315
    500 - 315 = 185.

    383 x 0.63 = 241.29
    383 - 241.29 = 141.71

    600 x 0.63 = 378
    600 - 378 = 222

    700 x 0.63 = 441
    700 - 441 = 259
```

answer : 809

809 != 791 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s$ be a scaling factor defined as $s = 791/2183.$

$500\times s  = 181.17\ldots$

$383\times s = 138.77\ldots $

$600\times s = 217.40\ldots$

$700\times s = 253.64\ldots$

Add these up:

$181.17\ldots+138.77\ldots+217.40\ldots+253.64\ldots = 791$

Comment: Oh man! thank you very much mate! :)